# Trying to download some python scripts from PythonAnywhere to my computer but it keeps opening another browser tab instead

Tags: pythonanywhere

I have some python scripts on PythonAnywhere.com that I am trying to download into my computer. Whenever I click the download icon next to the file, it opens into another web tab (Chrome) instead. I'm not sure what I did that caused this because I've been able to download files to my computer for the last couple of weeks but suddenly I cannot. Any help would be appreciated - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use your browser right-click menu on the download link to save the file to your disk.

Comment: There's no option for that. It's considers the file as an html link.

Comment: That's if you right-click on the filename, right-click on the download button.

Comment: oh thank you haha! I feel dumb for now figuring that out. By any chance do you know what could have caused this change though?

Comment: possibly the file type / the ending of the file? or possibly if your file had non-displayable content, then it would get downloaded vs if now your file is text/displayable then it displays?